# Change collapsed navbar color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know what CSS element must be edited to adjust bootstrap's collapsed navbar. Below is what I believe to be the CSS code of interest:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #0f4c92;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #0f4c92;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0f4c92;
  }
}
```

Hopefully I've captured the right selectors. Below are screenshots showing the the unselected collapsed nav (**which you can see is what I'm hoping to edit**), and then the selected collapsed nav. Ideally I'd like to make the unselected collapsed nav the same blue color, with 3 white stripes; I don't care if it's the same color scheme when active/selected.

[image: Unselected collapsed navbar]
[image: Selected collapsed navbar]

**Edit -- adding the HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/bestgatelogo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </nav><!--/nav-->
```

Comment: Provide a link or some of your header `HTML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want to change the `background-color` of the image on right, you need to edit class - `.navbar-toggle`
- For `border-color`, edit class - `.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle`
- For the 3 horizontal stripes, edit class - `.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar`

**Note -** You might need to add more weight to your selectors **OR** add `!important` to every CSS property. For example - `background-color: red !important`

Comment: I've added:

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #0f4c92;
  color: #fff;
}`` and

`.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #0f4c92;
  color: #fff;
}` but am still noticing that they are not doing the trick. I'll add the nabber HTML from the page in my question.

Comment: What is that you want exactly?

Comment: I'd like to edit the colors of the collapsed navbar. Right now when the page is viewed on a small viewport, all you see the image on the left, which is a white rectangle with the black outline, and a the inner icon-bar stripes are hidden white. I'd like to play with those colors such that the rectangle itself is blue, with the 3 white stripes.

Comment: Have a look at my 3rd point to change the color of the horizontal stripes

Comment: I believe that did the trick, actually. I might have fat-fingered my local css file before reviewing. Thanks!